# How to fetch More Offers products in WooCommerce?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

[image]

I want to customize the page and need to fetch products in "more offers". Which function I should use in WooCoommerce single page customizer plugin?

Comment: I understand. Can you please check the link of woocommerce website: https://directkeys.nl/product/diablo-3/

Comment: Please add this link, some more explanations and details editing your question. Now as I said, this is a customization made by your theme or by yourself (and doesn't exist in WooCommerce), so nobody can help you actually on that.  If this is related to your theme and you can't provide the related code, you should better contact theme's author support pages… Otherwise you should provide the related customization code *(in your question)*.